# Is there an F# Type Provider for Oracle?

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

Is there an F# Type Provider for Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's a type provider for Entity Framework contexts, and EF works with Oracle.

Comment: I will give it a try. Was just hoping that there is one directly supporting Oracle.

Comment: @auhorn - why would there be a type provider directly supporting Oracle when there isn't one directly supporting SQL Server? SqlDataConnection doesn't count - it's just a wrapper around the discontinued LINQ to SQL. It's a positive thing that we've got a type provider that uses an existing database-agnostic ORM instead of rolling its own - not a negative, as far as I can see.

Comment: It would actually be kind of awesome if there was a type provider which could generate code-first EF contexts on the fly. Would not be easy to write, though!

Comment: @JoelMueller - I am very new to this and still trying to get my head around it. and maybe there is still a puzzle piece missing to understand everything.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using SQLProvider, https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/

From their page:

```
#r "FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll" // only needed in .fsx script files

open FSharp.Data.Sql

type sql = SqlDataProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.ORACLE, connectionString, ResolutionPath = resolutionPath>
let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()

let customers = ctx.Customers |> Seq.toArray
```

I’ve even used SQLProvider to unit test functions in an Oracle database, not just to get at entities.

Also from their page:

```
ctx.Functions.UfnGetSalesOrderStatusText.Invoke(0uy)
```

Comment: Looks much better, @rowRobot. Thanks.